# Src starts with on Iframe

Tags: css, asp.net

This is my `iframe` and it contains lots of tables.

`<iframe id="DlgFramed4906422-9070-4604-bd1b-91c4216b088a" class="ms-dlgFrame" src="/Lists/Interne%20nyheder/DispForm.aspx?ID=68&amp;IsDlg=1" frameborder="0" style="width: 592px; height: 542px;"></iframe>`

I am trying to use `iframe[src^="/Lists/Interne%20nyheder/DispForm.aspx"]` but it don't seem to work on my page.

If I remove it from my css then the code below works just fine.

Css

```
iframe[src^="/Lists/Interne%20nyheder/DispForm.aspx"] {

    #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1 {
        .ms-formtoolbar {
            display: none;
        }

        .ms-formtable {
            /*width: 70%;*/
            tbody {
                tr {
                    td.ms-formlabel {
                        display: none;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this CSS or LESS/SCSS? You can not nest classes like that in regular CSS. It has to go through a compiler.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Sorry its less, Forgot to add it

Comment: Any reason you can not just use the class or ID?

Comment: The id is dynamic and made through sharepoint. And the class also exist on other iframes, the only differens if the src

Comment: I see. Your code seem correct to me. I am not sure why it is not working. Perhaps it is because "%20" is actually a space in the URL? Could you try with `[src^="/Lists/Interne nyheder/DispForm.aspx"]`?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Didnt seem to be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be something *else* that is wrong, but it is not the iFrame selector. I can verify that the CSS selector you use for the iFrame is indeed working. You can see this yourself in the minimal illustrative example below.

```css
iframe {
  border: 10px solid green !important;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
iframe[src^="/Lists/Interne%20nyheder/DispForm.aspx"] {
  border: 10px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="/Lists/Interne%20nyheder/DispForm.aspx">
</iframe>
```